# Multiple datepicker isnot working proper

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use multiple datepicker.But its not working properly.My problem is, when I click on text box for calendar, its loading after second click.Otherwise its working fine. I am unable to figure out the problem.I am giving my js code below :

```
$(".datepicker").on("click",function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function (date) 
            { 
              var date = $("#dateNew").val();//alert(date);
              var currDate = new Date();
            }
        });
```

Any idea, why this is creating problem?

Comment: Remove click event handler. i.e. `$(".datepicker").on("click",function(){`

Comment: can you post a fiddle of your problem?

Comment: I have place all the codes in there,here is my js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ZPyyZ/9/, I need to load calender in all the textbox ----Edward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your core with some changes:

```
$(function() {

        $(".datepicker").datepicker(
        {
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onSelect: function (date) 
            { 
              var date = $("#dateNew").val();//alert(date);
              var currDate = new Date();
            }
        });

        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" class="datepicker" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            $("input[name=p_scnt_" + i +"]").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                onSelect: function (date) 
                { 
                  var date = $("#dateNew").val();//alert(date);
                  var currDate = new Date();
                }
            });
                i++;

                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

Instead of creating datapicker after click, I create the new one when you add new input.

Comment: Its working only for one text box.Your code is working for first text box.I am using add more button for loading multiple text box.When I am clicking add more,it produced text box, your this code is not loading calender for second one.

Comment: Here is my working js fiddle link----fiddle link jsfiddle.net/ZPyyZ/9,